# Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/flexbox-layout/com/google/android/flexbox/1.0.0/flexbox-1.0.0.pom'

Tags: android, dependencies

I am using CometChat and ChatKit for building a chat app. When I execute the app in my Android phone, it appear error messages: "**Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/flexbox-layout/com/google/android/flexbox/1.0.0/flexbox-1.0.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project**"

Below is my Build Gradle project code:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://google.bintray.com/flexbox-layout" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        //jCenter()
        maven {
            url "https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/cometchat/cometchat-pro-android/maven/"
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon

        maven { url "https://google.bintray.com/flexbox-layout" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/inspection-plugin#important-deprecation-announcement), as you can see bintray has been shutted down. You should search in which repo the flexbox-layout has been deployed.

Comment: Hi, my problem still didn't solve by adding this line "implementation 'com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0'" in build gradle, I am not sure why adding this line doesn't work, it said :
"Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0. "

Comment: This is another kind of error. Probably you forgot to add a plugin or just badly copy/pasted addresses

Comment: I already checked my code for 3 times, and I also removed the bintray from gradle code, but it still didn't work...

Comment: I follow exactly the instruction based on this link: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout/issues/566#issuecomment-844630491